# How to get text without "\n" with xpath?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

i have code like that;

```
...
    <div class="col col-12 currentPrice">
    15,00
    $
    </div>
...
```

when i want to get 15$ with xpath ( `//descendant::div[@class="col col-12 currentPrice"]/text()` )
the output occurs like `"\n15,00\n$\n"`.
So how can i get data without `\n`?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\s+', '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [w3lib](https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html?highlight=strip%20%5Cn#w3lib.http.headers_raw_to_dict) package to get red of \n, white space. please check it.

```
>>> import w3lib.html
>>> w3lib.html.strip_html5_whitespace(' hello \n')
'hello'
>>> w3lib
w3lib
>>> w3lib.html.strip_html5_whitespace("\n15,00\n$\n")
'15,00\n$'
>>> w3lib.html.strip_html5_whitespace("\n15,00\n$\n").strip('\n')
'15,00\n$'
>>> w3lib.html.strip_html5_whitespace("\n15,00\n$\n").split('\n')
['15,00', '$']
>>> ''.join(w3lib.html.strip_html5_whitespace("\n15,00\n$\n").split('\n'))
'15,00$'
>>>
```